# fastest way to read file and do put into hbase

Tags: java, file, hbase

I am trying to read data from txt files and place into an hbase table. I have approximately 10 billion records in those files and the expectation is that I need to finish it in a day or two. The problem is that it is up to day 3 and not complete. The following code is applied in about 10 different processes with the files separated accordingly. Would having multiple individual threads in each process been a better approach and if so how would the code be set up?

```
 for (File file : fList){
      System.out.println(file.getName());
      fileCount +=1;
      try {

          FileInputStream inputStream = null;
          Scanner sc = null;
          BufferedReader reader = null;
          inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
          sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
          while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
              String line = sc.nextLine();
              lineCount+=1;

              String[] pmeters = line.split("\\ ");
              String clientID=pmeters[0];
              String famID = pmeters[1];

              byte[] currRecord;
              put(famID,clientID,"");
              htable.flushCommits();

          }



      } finally {

    }       

  }
```

Comment: I'd *guess* that the commit call takes most of the time; see if you can make it ever 10, 100, or 1000 records...

Comment: We usually put data in csv file and then use commands to put the whole file into the database, not records one by one. 1m data is done pretty quickly. Should be okey with billions as well. Although that's for postgres. This is just a possible idea.

Comment: Mikelis, can you put a csv file into an hbase table?

Comment: Tassos, I will to spread out the commit.

Comment: thanks for the comments, so is it correct that this process technically could be done in mere hours. What about threading with the file reading?

Comment: Have you tried hbase "bulkload".  : [1] http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html#completebulkload [2] http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/

Comment: Bulk file load is best solution, but you can expect to insert 10billion in one day if you write it with multi thread and batch. You should call put(List<Put> ) method of api with 1000 puts in that list.

Answer (score 0):

### use batch commit and multi thread

many put object into a list ( List )
and use `table.put(list)`
put data not recommended single put, recommended use batch commit.

if the file is single file,split it to many file. and use multi thread
the HTable object you can close the autoflush and set writebuffcache

---

### use preset partition with hbase table (this is important for proformance)

like : `create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit'}`
or `create 'testSplit','Cf',{SPLITS=>['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' ]}`

the preset partition is must matching the rowkey.
english is not good,can't say the preset partition to clear.you can google it.

---

### on server if necessary

> in hbase-site.xml

`hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit set to 0.6 default 0.4`

`hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.lowerLimit set to 0.55  default 0.38`

`hfile.block.cache.size  set to 0.2   default 0.4`

this setting can increase the write memstore size and lessen block cache size for query.or you can set value by u self if you want.

Remember `upperLimit + cache.size must <=0.8`

`hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size default 32M`
you can compute get the result to set flush.size:
if regionserver has 16G heap.   lowerLimit is 0.55    and if single regionserver have count of 100 region.
`(16*1024MB * 0.55) / 100 = 90MB` 
you can set the flush to 80MB
this set purpose to make suer the flush memstore is scattered , is not concentrate to do flush work.

if you can , set hbase.regionserver.optionalcacheflushinterval value of 0